# Failing to install the latest version of Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services, installation, windows-installer

I am installing a Windows Service on my Desktop with a particular version. Then I revise my service and make some changes in the service.I upgrade my installer version.I  make the property RemovePreviousVersion true and I do the following things below.In Custom Action I add **NOT PREVIOUSVERSIONSINSTALLED**  and then I add below mentioned code.

```
System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController serviceController = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController("WinDbSync1");
        if (serviceController.Status != System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
        {
            serviceController.Start();

        }
```

I have got tha above solution from link [Installing Higher Versions of existing Windows Service in VS 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538064/installing-higher-versions-of-existing-windows-service-in-vs-2008.Despite) following above steps ,It installs the windows Service but *doesnot execute the business functionality written in Install event*.Please let me know if I am missing any step.Also I am not changing the version of exe.I am simply changing version of Installer.

Regards,

Sachin K

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for custom actions to install the service. Windows Installer has built in support.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371634(v=vs.85).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371637(v=VS.85).aspx